# Unable to parse xpath locator with regexp for Selenium locator with normalized-space and concat function

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath, concatenation

I spent enormous number of hours trying to create needed regex for the following xpath:

```
//button[(@*[normalize-space()='concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")' or text()[normalize-space()='concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")')]|//input[@*[normalize-space()='concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")' or text()[normalize-space()='concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")']
```

The result should be the following --> concat should NOT be wrapped in ' ' .

```
//button[(@*[normalize-space()=concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!") or text()[normalize-space()=concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!"))]|//input[@*[normalize-space()=concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!") or text()[normalize-space()=concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")]
```

So I have to locate this part of text : `concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")`
and then to apply matcher --> `concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")`

I understand that my regexp should look something like :

```
(=')((concat\()([\'|\"].+[\'|\"]))(\)')$
```

starting with `='`
then `concat(`
then `some expression` for the inner text for the concat function (here I'm having issues)
then that the expression should end with `)'`

BUT for some reason my regex just doesn't work!

Would you mind explaining me my problem?

Answer (score 0):

To match `concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")` you can use:

`"concat\\(['\"].*?['\"],\\s*['\"].*?['\"],\\s*['\"].*?['\"]\\)"`

Comment: Yes, thanks. It works for 
concat('Let', "'", "s have fun!")

I spent some more time and finally came up with the following (matches every concat('')) that I need.
='(concat)((\([\'|\"]){1}([^)])*\)['])